# slidingmenu at android5.0 can not refresh the main UI, below 5.0 runs ok

Tags: slidingmenu

My app use a slidingmenu and a viewpager which contains some fragments. There is a fragment with a scrollview.

When at Android 5.0 moblie phone, I find that this fragment’s UI can't be dragged at vertical direction.

For example, when I try to scroll the UI to the top, it don't change,though the log show that touchevents goes normal; then I slide the slidingmenu, is changed and has scrolled to the right position I has scrolled before; it sounds like the UI does not update when I was scrolling up and down, but update when I slide the slidingmenu.

However, I have never found this problem before when I test it in moblie phone which below version 5.0.

Answer (score 2):

You can try add"android:hardwareAccelerated="true"" in your manifest file,that works for me. You can try whether it helps .

-maybe this is a bug